# Can I set more than one hyper links on single word?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I want to know that Can I set more than one links on single word in html?
I've experimented like:

- `<a href="link1" target="_self"><a href="link2 target="_blank>Open</a></a>`
- `<a href="link1" target="_self" href="link2" target="_blank">Open</a>`

This is only example idea what I want to do ; of-course either of above is not working.

So, **How can I set more than one links to different target on single word?**
Is it possible with html or `<a>` or something else.

Comment: This makes no sense. The `<a>` tag has the attribute `href` that links to the target site through a hyperlink URL, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Do a search for JavaScript pop-up menus. It sounds like what you really want is for a user to be able to click on a link and then get a choice of which target page to go to.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

If you are open for javascript you could create a function that takes urls and have the function call [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) but that is likely to get blocked by pop-up blockers.

```js
/* this function tries to open the
   arguments supplied to it*/
function opensesame() {
  for(var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    $('#log').append($('<div></div>').text('trying to open '+ arguments[i]));
    window.open(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- you can have a local link in href -->
<a href="#" 
   onclick="opensesame('http://www.google.com','http://stackoverflow.com');">
  open sesame
</a>

<div id="log">
</div>
```

From the [FAQ on the window.open documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> **How can I tell when my window was blocked by a popup blocker?**
>   With the built-in popup blockers of Mozilla/Firefox and Internet Explorer 6 SP2, you have to check the return value of window.open(): it will be null if the window wasn't allowed to open. However, for most other popup blockers, there is no reliable way.

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to extend this to take `target` settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

It's possible to have two different links in different parts of the same word, but not on the same.

```
<a href="l1">unif</a><a href="l2">orm</a>
```

You need Javascript for such thing.